# SQL DB Role to get View Definition permission

Tags: azure-synapse-analytics

In Azure Synapse Serverless SQL Pool looking for an inbuilt DB Role that can be assigned to an SPN which can then read the definition of all views.

I know that we do have the "GRANT VIEW DEFINITION" permission option. But I am looking for a DB role option.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by using the built Fixed Database role 'db_securityadmin'.

Here is the link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver16

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).